# Accessing USB device from Terminal requires root?

Tags: terminal, usb, permission, migration

I have an AtmelICE, which is a USB microcontroller programmer. I just bought a new MBP and used migration assistant to migrate from my old MBP. On the old one, I was able to run a program called avrdude to use this programmer as my own user. The new MBP requires me to 'sudo' to use it. Otherwise, I get this error:

`avrdude: usbdev_open(): error claiming interface 0: Permission denied`

I've granted the Terminal full disk access. Is there some other permission I need to grant it (that presumably wasn't migrated by the migration assistant)?

I also have a USBTiny programmer, and avrdude can open that one just fine without sudo, so there must be some nuance here.

Comment: macOS is not like FreeBSD where you can set udev rules as you see fit. Accessing any of the devices directly requires root privileges.

Comment: Then why does it work without sudo on my old MBP?

Comment: It’s not the Mac itself but the macOS version. What were you using oreviously?

Comment: Did the programmer have native macOS drivers?

Comment: No. It does have an "empty kext" that forces it to be available to libusb instead of as a HID device, but that was migrated properly by the migration assistant.

Comment: That may no longer be functional on this new version of macOS.

Comment: Once again, it works just fine on the old MBP - same MacOS - 13.4

Comment: I struggled with this very thing and gave up.  I put FreeBSD  on a white MacBook and used that to talk to my BeagleBone

Comment: Welp, be comforted that there is SOME solution out there, if you and I don't know it at the moment.